# JNA - Call a native C++ function from a returned Pointer to Struct from DLL

Tags: java, c++, jna

My question is how can I call a function from a struct which is returned as a pointer from initial call to a native c++ function. (I havent developed the.dll)

Guessing the c++ export functions

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) unsigned int MTManagerVersion(int &version) { 
// some c++ code
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) unsigned int MTManagerCreate(int version, ManagerAPI **managerAPI) {
// some c++ code
}
```

In the Java world I have done the following:

Load the native dll file and define the dll export functions.

```
public interface MTManagerAPIFactory extends Library {

MTManagerAPIFactory INSTANCE = Native.load(".\\MT5APIManager64.dll", ManagerAPIFactory.class);

    int MTManagerVersion(IntByReference version);

    int MTManagerCreate(int version, PointerByReference pointer);
}
```

Define the class that the pointer refers to the structure. Please note that the structure contains only functions not even a single field/variable.

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({"Disconnect", "Connect"})
public class IMTManagerAPI extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference {

    public IMTManagerAPI() {
        super();
    }

    public IMTManagerAPI(Pointer address) {
        super(address);
        read();
    }

    public interface Connect extends Callback {

        public int Connect(String server, int login, String password, String password_cert, int pump_mode, int timeout);
    }

    public interface Disconnect extends Callback {

        void Disconnect();
    }

    public Disconnect Disconnect;
    public Connect Connect;
}
```

Finally putting all together wihtin main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int response;

// get version
IntByReference version = new IntByReference();
response = MTManagerAPIFactory.INSTANCE.MTManagerVersion(version);
System.out.println(String.format("ManagerAPI Version %s (response %s)", version.getValue(), response));

// create manager api
PointerByReference managerAPIByReference = new PointerByReference();
response = MTManagerAPIFactory.INSTANCE.MTManagerCreate(version.getValue(), managerAPIByReference);
System.out.println(String.format("ManagerAPI Create(response %s)", response));

if (managerAPIByReference.getValue() == null) {
    System.out.println("\nWARN: Return pointer is null..\n");
}
IMTManagerAPI manager = new IMTManagerAPI(managerAPIByReference.getValue());
// invalid memory access
manager.Disconnect.Disconnect();
}
```

After running the application I get the following:

> ManagerAPI Version 1881 (response 0)
>
> ManagerAPI Create(response 0)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access     at
> com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(Native Method)  at
> com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:414)    at
> com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:360)    at
> com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:314)    at
> com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$NativeFunctionHandler.invoke(CallbackReference.java:679)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.Disconnect(Unknown Source)
> at App.main(App.java:28)

Note: Althought I dont want to use callback I dont find any other way to call the function within a struct.

Any ideas/assist thank you!

P.S. I have read a lot of other similar answer on stack overflow ,no luck.

Update #1 Manager API header can be found [here](https://ufile.io/oihp5)

Comment: Do you have the definition for `ManagerAPI`? Could you include that at least partially in your question?

Comment: I have upload the header file of the Manager API [here](https://ufile.io/oihp5)

Comment: Yeah, that's a C++ class with methods marked `virtual`. JNA does not have support for C++ classes.

Comment: What is the recommended approach? Excluding the one to wrap the c++ lib with c code.

Comment: Looking at the header, you'd want to write your own C++ wrapper which exports C-style functions you can use from JNA. Or look further into the API you're provided with to see if it has support for C and see how it's used from C, then see how you'd use that from JNA.

Comment: `ManagerAPI` must be a plain C struct in order for this to work.  Please add the `ManagerAPI` definition to your question.

Comment: I have upload the header file in this link https://ufile.io/yhfa6. Please let me know if there is anything else missing. Looking forward for your feedback!